# Capybara for testing tooltip contents fails randomly only in Semaphore

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, jquery-tooltip

My specs passes in local. But the below code fails in Semaphore CI.
- Included `js: true`
- Tried increasing the `Capybara.default_wait_time` to 5, but still no luck.

Here is my code:

```
find(".tooltip-#{user.id}").hover
expect(page).to have_content user.tooltip_content
```

Any idea how this can be resolved.

Comment: have you solved your problem? I'm having the same problem, maybe you can add `config.ignore_localhost = true` on your vcr config file. It didn't work for me though.

Comment: @AndréHerculano Not solved the problem yet. The issue sporadic and I don't get this issue sometimes when rebuild is given in CI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

`page.execute_script('$(".tooltip-#{user.id}").mouseover()')`

`expect(page).to have_content user.tooltip_content`